# How can I have a Unity Android app handle an intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity app and I want it to handle an ACTION_VIEW intent from another app, specifically to open a video file. I understand how I would do it with a native Android app, but I have no idea how to cause the Unity activity to be able to receive intents:

- I know how to change its AndroidManifest.xml, but what exactly should I put there?
- Should I write some kind of an Android Plugin to handle the intent? How?

Answer (score 0):

This posts explains how to intercept intent for your Unity app: https://blog.getsocial.im/android-unity-app-and-the-intent-issue/

General idea is that you have to write a plugin with Activity that handles you video flow, put it into manifest like in simple android app and open the main activity after the video handling job is done.